# How to authenticate using client library for GCP in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, .net-6.0, google-cloud-pubsub

So I want to work with GCP Pub/Sub in a C# Environment but I want to know how to authenticate by passing parameters to some Function or Constructor I'm looking specifically for it to work with Cloud Pub/Sub.

This is the code I currently have:

```
var client = new PublisherClientBuilder { 
    Credential = <I dont Know this part yet>
}.Build();
```

I have searched for 3 days and the closest I got was `PublisherServiceApiClientBuilder` but I couldn't find a way to authenticate using it I'm on .NET 6.0 using C#.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/help/client-configuration#specifying-credentials

Comment: Note that at the moment, you don't say how you *want* to authenticate - using a service account? Application default credentials? Something else?

Comment: i would like to be able to authenticate in code thats it

Comment: No, "thats it" isn't *nearly* enough detail. There are all kinds of authentication options - different identities you can authenticate as, different ways of providing the credentials for those identities etc. The equivalent as an *answer* would be "you specify the credential to assign in your code - that's it". If that wouldn't be enough detail as an answer, consider that you aren't providing enough detail in your question...